# Problems dynamically creating javascript chart

Tags: php, html, charts

1) HTML file
2) PHP file

HTML File:
Objective: Input a string in the textbox and post to the php file
`<form method="post" action="lineChartSql3.php">`
Merchant Id

Start Date `<input type="text" name="Start_Date" value="" />`

PHP file:
Objective: Gets the input and pass it to the javascript code which dynamically  generates graph
Problem: I get Highchart error #13

```
    $startDate = $_POST["Start_Date"];



    $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                     //renderTo: 'container',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Number of People queueing',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: TickTok.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
            //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
               // 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
             title: {
                text: 'No. of people queueing'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            //valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the HTML of your PHP page look like? According to [Highcharts' error page,](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13&ei=NoqTUdGrNbOh7AbK64DwDA&usg=AFQjCNHNcHIDbEcSVIlWsrdzebGiAUNX-w&bvm=bv.46471029,d.ZGU) Error #13 means you're missing the HTML element.

My guess is that you don't have an element with the ID of 'container' on your page.

I.e. you need something like:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

By using:

```
 $('#container').highcharts //etc
```

You're using jQuery to select by ID 'container' and then using that HTML object reference to load the chart in. Make sure you have a HTML element with that ID and that you have jQuery included.

Comment: I have that in the body tag of the php file:

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
 
 <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <button id="get_button">Update </button>

Comment: Do you have any other errors in the Javascript console (press F12 and go to console in most browsers)? Do you have jQuery included in a script tag on that page?

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you want to know, how you can pass a "value" from PHP to the highcharts Javascript?

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$categories = array("Jan","Feb");
echo '<script language="javascript">';
//results in var myCategories = ['Jan','Feb'];
echo 'var myCategories = [\''.implode("','".$categories).'\'];';
echo '</script>';
?>

<script language="javascript">
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
        categories: myCategories;
    },
    ...
</script>
```

Just generate the part of javascript, containing the values with PHP.